# Printing standard in raw implementations

Tags: printing, newline, standards

I'm making my little toy stack-language, and am revolving it around a central concept of Bytecode, literally just like the JVM.

One of the opcodes I want to add in, is a `print_var` function, that will print the value of a local variable. My question is, which print function do I use? `println()`, or `print()`?

Well really, it's not a question of what to use, but **what is the standard in actual applications of this process**? Are systems designed to simply `print()`, and then a `println()` function is built around the `print()` function, or are they both made hand-in-hand to do seperate things?

I'm taking a look at Java's `PrintWriter` source, which is used in `System.out.println()`, and its defined as follows:

```
public void println(boolean x) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        print(x);
        println();
    }
}
```

Obviously Java made a `print()` function and based the `println()` off of it. Are many other major languages like that?

Comment: @GhostCat No problem. I normally wait a few days for good answers and forgot all about you by accident sorry! Since then, I've implemented both `print` and `printLn` and I'm fairly happy with the decision. Thankyou!.

Comment: You are very welcome:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see:

- C: has [printf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm) --- no println
- C++: has [ostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/) -- no println
- C#: has [WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=VS.100).aspx) (and Write)
- Haskell: has [putStr](https://wiki.haskell.org/Learn_Haskell_in_10_minutes#The_console) and putStrLn
  ...

Long story short: you can find both. So simply implement what *you* think works best for your requirements respectively your approach in general. In other words: simply have a look at the *other* opcodes you have/want to implement and assess if they are more about "convenience" (so you would have print and println), or if they focus on providing "elementary building blocks" (then you might only provide print).

Beyond that: keep in mind that providing println() has one *major* advantage: the user doesn't need to worry about different "new line" characters for different operating systems.